# Review this proof of least upper bounds?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a subset of real numbers, and $x$ is a real number.

Let $B=\{a+x | a \in A\}$.

Show that if $A$ has the least upper bound $\sup A$, then $B$ also has the least upper bound $\sup B = \sup A + x$.

Proof:

Let $\sup A = Y$. By definition of least upper bound, $a \le Y$ for all $a \in A$.

Then $a+x \le Y+x$, and $Y+x$ can be written as $\sup A + x$.

$B=\{a+x\ | a \in A \}$, so $b=a+x$ for $b \in B$.

Thus, $b \le \sup A + x$, implying that the least upper bound of $B$ is $b=\sup A + x$, or $\sup B=\sup A + x$.

Does this seem sufficient? Thank you!

Comment: That's not sufficient. You only showed that $\sup B \leq \sup A + x$. But not the equality.

Answer (score 0):

I would say $B = A+x$, not $B = a+x$. But that's minor.

More importantly, you have shown that $Y + x$ is an upper bound of $B$, but not a least upper bound. This part is still left to show. Note that you have only used the fact that $Y$ was an upper bound of $A$, you didn't use the fact that it was a least upper bound yet.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

All you've shown is that $Y + x$ is an upper bound for $B$. How do you know that it's the **least** upper bound?

To this end, choose any $\epsilon > 0$. We want to find some $b \in B$ such that $b > (Y + x) - \epsilon$. Now since $Y = \sup A$, we know that there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a > Y - \epsilon$. Hence, by taking $b = a + x \in B$, we have that:
$$
b = a + x > (Y - \epsilon) + x = (Y + x) - \epsilon
$$
as desired.

Comment: And this is sufficient to demonstrate that Y+x is the least upper bound (supremum) of B? I'm not sure I follow how this is the case - could you please explain the reasoning?

Comment: @user175172, you showed one direction, this one just shows you the other direction to complete the equality.

Comment: To see why $Y + x$ is the **least** upper bound of $B$, choose any number less than $Y + x$ (for example, $Y + x - \epsilon$). Then we want to show that $Y + x - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $B$ (otherwise, that would contradict the minimality of $Y + x$). So to show that $Y + x - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $B$, it suffices to find some $b \in B$ that is not bounded above by $Y + x - \epsilon$ (that is, we want that $b > (Y + x) - \epsilon$).